# checksum of a file in javascript

Tags: javascript, encryption, hash, checksum

I have a use case where if a user uploads a file and then before it gets uploaded, I want to calculate a checksum on that file within the browser. I found couple of libraries but for files more than 3 GB, the calculation time is too much so was wondering is there any way this can be achieved in JS.

Referred below article:

https://medium.com/@0xVaccaro/hashing-big-file-with-filereader-js-e0a5c898fc98

Comment: The bottleneck is probably reading the file, not calculating the checksum, there's no way around that.

Comment: Are you reading the full file into memory to calculate the sum ? Don't do that. Show us your code.

Comment: found a library which does that which I posted above. So thats the code and I guess they load it in browser or read bytes from local machine.